# Can't install cocos2D-x blank project on any Android emulator

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I get:

```
 [echo] Installing /Users/funk/Development/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/MyGame/proj.android/bin/MyGame-debug.apk onto default emulator or device...
 [exec] ADB server didn't ACK
 [exec] * failed to start daemon *
 [exec] error: cannot connect to daemon
 [exec] cannot bind 'tcp:5037
```

I tried manually installing it using adc install  and got a similar error.

I've tried this on a device emulator for API8 and API15. Btw I am a complete n00b with android stuff. I feel completely lost in the woods compared to my old C++ dev or when i first did iOS dev.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new Emulator from Emulator manager and you must enable OpenGLES when creating your Android emulator. If you are in doubt, please google it, there are many documents here and there.

After creating your emulator, you should start it at first. When the emulator is finish launching, you could use the build_native.py scripts to install cocos2d-x to emulator now.

NB, don't try to run cocos2d-x on Android emulator, the emulator is very slow and error prone.

And many features are only available in real Android device.

So I would suggest anyone who start cocos2d-x prefer device to emulator.

For installing apk to Android real device, you should at first enable your USB remote debugging. If you don't

And then connect your Android phone to your computer with USB hub.

To verify whether your phone is connected, you should do this:

```
adb devices
```

If it gives you some devices information, then you could run the build_native.py scripts and install the apk to your phone.

Comment: I've heard about using a native device from many places. It's quite sad, considering the ios simulator works perfectly fine for games.

Still I would heed the advice, even if only that understand the UX with touch is better with a device, however I don't own an android phone. The whole point of the game was to surprise my girlfriends with a simple platformer game when we met up after the holidays... those plans have really gone south as I've spent 6 days fumbling with cocos2d-x without writing a single line of code.

Comment: You might need to take a look at the programming guide:http://www.cocos2d-x.org/programmersguide/

Comment: I'll take another look, although I'm pretty sure I've already read the entire thing by now.
Btw I couldn't find a "build_native.py". I found a "build-nacl.sh", but it gives the error "x86_64-nacl-gcc: command not found"

Comment: ok wait, you just honestly recommended the programming guide, when it doesn't contain a single reference on how to actually test your program... [emulator or device...] Have you read the programming guide?

Comment: Oh I see now. I'm sorry about that. I went straight to the PDF and epub versions, because I didn't notice the table of contents on the left of the webpage. Their download versions don't have appendices.

Regardless, I well look at these tomorrow when i wake up. Thank you very much for pointing me to a promising source of information.

Comment: Ok, I tried going through the steps and everything went smoothly until the first ambiguous step: "python android-build.py -p <target # from above> cpp-tests"
Copying and pasting that didn't work. I tried using -p19 for the API level,that didn't work, then i tried "-p 19 ../tests/cpp-tests" that gave me the error "unknown target ../tests/cpp-tests/" [the directory definitely exists, I tabbed to it.]